# Change Calligraphy default font not in application class

Tags: java, android, calligraphy

I have a multi language application and using [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/) for setting the font.

I want to change [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/) default font when the user changes app locale.